# How can I remove marks off a plastic phone back?

Tags: cleaning, phone, stain

After a while of using a case, the dirt that gets stuck in the case leaves kinda very severe marks on the plastic back of the phone. I have searched everywhere on Google but the results are just how to remove the marks off a *case*, I want to remove the marks off a *phone*.

Comment: Welcome to Lifehacks! It would really help if you can make some photos of what exactly you're talking about. Perhaps you can borrow a friend's phone?

Answer (score 2):

- First clean the case with a *damp* cloth, barely wet with mostly water and a drop of detergent. If any water gets into the device, it may be damaged, so wring the cloth thoroughly before use.
- If there's still dirt (not scratches), wipe with a cloth barely wet with rubbing alcohol. Again, don't let it get into the device.
- If scratches are not too deep, remove by rubbing with a fine, mild abrasive. There are various tools for polishing scratched and dirty plastic, such as a [kit for a high-speed rotary tool](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000OZ57WW), but first I'd try these polishing compounds found at home:

  - Milk of magnesia, Mg(OH)<sub>2</sub> or
  - Toothpaste

  This requires **a lot** of gentle rubbing with a clean cloth, such as a microfiber cleaning cloth, covered with the compound. Keep polishing until scratches are removed, or the compound dries out, then reapply.